# How do you earn the "I'm Not Listening" hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

The secret "I'm Not Listening" hat:

[image: I'm Not Listening]

It clearly requires you to ignore something. But *what* exactly?

[image: La la la!]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Indeed, you need to turn a deaf ear towards something.

If you really want to know, listen *carefully* to the spoiler below:

[image: Listening carefully]

> You need to reject a suggested edit on one of your **own** posts.

Comment: I want more spoilers like this.

Comment: Eureka! (Hint hint... another secret hat...) :-P

Comment: Does rollback count as a rejection?

Comment: @CodeMaverick: I don't think so.

Comment: @insert, I made a post to be a bit more vague than this answer but give you a more fighting chance [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212799/).

Comment: It's so simple I could suggest anonymously and then reject it :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson you could, but then we would suspend you and take away all of your hats. (You're probably joking, but if we catch anyone gaming the system just to earn a hat, that's what will happen.)

Comment: @Laura way to have a mod ruin the fun

Comment: @ColeJohnson hey, I've got to earn my paycheck somehow!

Comment: @Laura You're really going to suspend the hundreds of people who've been asking a mediocre-but-socially-acceptable question just to get a hat, who've upvoted each others' comments and meta answers and starred chat messages just to get a hat, who made retags with bogus new tags just to get a hat, who've given out bounties just to get a hat, etc.?

Comment: @Laura How about [taking their lunch money, hanging them on a high pole using their undies, and disclosing their browsing history](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/gaming-the-site-for-hat-farming/1472#1472)?

Comment: +1 for Gilles, and I might add those hundreds of people are SE's most active contributors, by definition.

Comment: @Laura I forgot upvoting while refraining from downvoting. An easy hat to game, and you can't possibly prove violations.

Comment: @Gilles The tag one is arguably not cool, because if I understand you correctly you're saying people have created bad tags and added them to questions just to get a hat... Which pollutes the site. But all the rest of it seems harmless to me. I admit I played the comment upvoting game on that ELU meta post. It was fun. As long as there's no lasting negative effect on the site by gaming the hat, I don't see what's wrong with doing so. If the point isn't to try to get the hats, they'd probably all be secret and a lot harder to figure out.

Comment: @WendiKidd In the tag case, I'm not sure whether they were solely intending to get the hat or trying to pinpoint the criteria (it's a secret hat). Given the ugly turn this is taking, I am not going to name names.

Comment: @wendi I created two new tags for a hat, but I made sure that those were good tags. there usually is scope for a good new tag on any site you visit.

Comment: I got the tag hat by complete accident. But, for example, what I *have* been doing very much on purpose is moving between chat rooms, talking to different people about different things, getting an occasional star and moving on. Reviving rooms, meeting new people. Now, is that gaming yet? Or is it rather *the very purpose of the hat*? All hats are a game to begin with. I've been active for years on a wide range of sites, editing, posting, reviewing, flagging, voting, but that alone is not enough. I wouldn't be getting the hats for these activities if I weren't specifically aiming for them.