# How Do I Get the Winterbash 2013 Secret Hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013, secret-hats

> My intention is not to spoil any of the secret hats. These are ones that anyone who looks at the leaderboard can see, and I have no intention of telling you exactly how to get any of them. However, giving people a nudge in the right direction seems to be fair game.

### List of Known Secret Hats:

> [image] **Before It Was Cool**
> [image] **Chuck Yeager**
> [image] **Eureka!**
> [image] **Ghost of Winterbash Past**
> [image] **I See Your Point**
> [image] **IG-88**
> [image] **I'm Not Listening**
> [image] **Johnny Three-Hats**
> [image] **With Great Power...**
> [image] **Don Draper**

### Shog9's Riddles of Confusion

Shog9 [gives hints on 10 secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211750/209637):

1. ...then I took an arrow to the knee.
2. Earned ten of the most meaningless points on the 'Net
3. I live... AGAIN!
4. He ain't no drag
5. from JBM to JWH
6. Humpty Dumpty, or perfect in every way?
7. There are only so many people capable of putting together words that stir and move and sing.
8. You look like an absolute idiot.
9. You may have to go to Puerto Vallarta, break the law and then fight extradition to get over this one.
10. Solve these riddles and it's yours

Comment: Eureka! The tenth hat is revealed as the "Don Draper"!

Answer (score 26):

### [image] Chuck Yeager

*"[from JBM to JWH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wesley_Hardin)"*

> John Wesley Hardin was an outlaw, he may have even been the Fastest Gun in the West, which seems to be a problem discussed here on Meta

---

### [image] Ghost of Winterbash Past

*"[I live... AGAIN!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159229/209637)"*

> This hat was given out last year, and apparently you can get him the exact same way as you did back then...

---

### [image] I See Your Point

*"[Earned ten of the most meaningless points on the 'Net](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122029/209637)"*

> This is the meta version of another, non-secret hat...

---

### [image] Before It Was Cool

*"[He ain't no drag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papa%27s_Got_a_Brand_New_Bag)"*

> Come here sister.....Papa's in the swing
>  He ain't too hip...about that new breed babe
>  He ain't no drag
>  Papa's got a brand new <strike>bag</strike> tag?

---

### [image] Eureka!

*"Solve these riddles and it's yours"*

> This one seems to be awarded manually, allegedly

---

### [image] IG-88

*"[You may have to go to Puerto Vallarta, break the law and then fight extradition to get over this one.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duane_Chapman)"*

> IG-88 was one of the Bounty Hunters from Star Wars. Duane Chapman was a real bounty hunter who ended up arrested when pursuing a bounty.

---

### [image] I'm Not Listening

*"[Humpty Dumpty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty), or [perfect in every way](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Mary_Poppins_%28film%29)?"*

> Humpty Dumpty appears in *Through the Looking Glass* making mistakes in English and saying, *"When I use a word it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less."*, and Mary Poppins is *"practically perfect in every way"*. Perhaps this is for those who don't take well to constructive criticism in some way?

---

### [image] Johnny Three-Hats

*"[You look like an absolute idiot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8K1fTZaR7w)"*

> Johnny Two-hats looked like an idiot, but if you collect more hats than him *fast enough*, you can be the idiot king.

---

### [image] Don Draper

*"[There are only so many people capable of putting together words that stir and move and sing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyril_M._Kornbluth) [When it became possible to earn a very good living in advertising by exercising this capability, lyric poetry was left to untalented screwballs who had to shriek for attention and compete by eccentricity.](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/465835-there-are-only-so-many-people-capable-of-putting-together)"*

> Hint: advertising

---

### [image] With Great Power...

*"...then I took an arrow to the knee."*

> This is a meme from the Skyrim game where a character says, *"I used to be an adventurer like you, then I took an arrow to the knee"*. My guess is that this may be related to the Great Power badge, since those who have it used to be users just like us, but then they took an <strike>arrow</strike> diamond to the knee.

Comment: Does a guy with three hats look like an idiot?

Comment: @Bergi, he may, but I can't see how that would be a riddle. Though it makes sense.

Comment: *Humpty Dumpty or Perfect in every way* is what I had paired up with "With Great Power...", but it goes with "I'm not Listening" as well. *You look like an absolute idiot* **definitely** goes with "Johnny Three-hats*. Look up "Johnny Two-hats" instead and you'll know why.

Comment: *...then I took an arrow to the knee.* is another 'hipster' reference. Yeah, I used to do that too, but then I ...

Comment: As for Cyril's words, there is a writing competition going on here on Meta..

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's what I was thinking, just waiting four more hours to see if I get a shiny new hat :) Currently second-place.

Comment: Before It Was Cool makes perfect sense, once you earn it.  And I did.  ;o)

Comment: "With great powers come great responsabilities." - Uncle Ben.

Comment: You've got more than ten in your answer, don't you?

Comment: @Bergi Not sure, but the guy with 3 upvotes on comment surely does! #jk